# Creating dynamic legend in ArcMap that summiaries areas of polygon based on Data Driven Pages layout

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend, layouts, data-driven-pages

I have a land use polygon layer with around 700 maps to produce using Data Driven Pages in ArcMap.

I am trying to create a dynamic legend that summarises the areas M2 based on the layout extent. The layout extents and maps are produced using data driven pages but I do not want to have to manually create 700 legends of summarised data.

I need the legend to display the area of each landuse type based on the map extent.

I have five land use types:

- Grass
- Shrubs
- Water
- Hard standing
- Wildflower Meadow